# Installing .Net 4.5.2 on Windows 7 (without any SP installed)

Tags: windows-7, installation, .net-framework

Is it possible to install .Net 4.5.2 on a clean Windows 7 without any service packs installed?

I am asking since the release notes for 4.0 state

```
- Windows 7
- Windows 7 SP1
```

while the 4.5.2 only state

```
- Windows 7 SP1
```

However, the accompanying text on the download page says

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 is a highly compatible, in-place update to the Microsoft .NET Framework 4, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1.

So, what is the case now? Is it highly compatible and can be installed on Windows 7 (no sp), or can it only be installed on Win7 SP1?

Comment: Technically speaking, it should work. But may I ask why you have this question? Are you not going to install SP1?

Comment: I have to create an installer for an application that requires .Net 4. I thought it might make sense to bundle the latest web installer for ease of use, but some people might install the app on non-SP1 windows and I don't want to force a dependency on SP1.

Comment: The simple answer.  Don't provide support to Windows 7 RTM.  The requirements are pretty clear

Comment: But then the people running Win 7 without SP1 might not give us money.

Comment: There will be very little people (if at all) who run Win 7 RTM, because Win7 SP1 is given for free with windows updates. As @Ramhound says, don't support them. Its not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Wilbert - If they can't be bothered to install Windows 7 SP1 then more then just your software won't work. Furthermore `.NET Framework 4.5.2` won't install on `Windows 7 RTM` anyways

Comment: That's really not the point. Other software not running is not the reason for them not to give us money. Our software not running is.

Comment: I guess some people here are missing the point: There is no such thing as “we don’t support it” with enterprise software development. You think you can drop support for Windows XP or Office 2000? Wrong. You can’t. Big companies are nigh immovable behemoths. Even a single patch could take months of testing.

Comment: Any IT department not running Windows 7 SP1 should be hauled out and shot in the event of a malware episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I was able to install .Net 4.5.2 on Virtual Machine with clean Windows 7 x64 (no SP1) via web installer.